# C: NaCl how to create 'PPB_Graphics3D

Tags: c, webgl, google-nativeclient

In Native Client, how do I create a proper instance of `PPB_Graphics3D` in C (not C++)??

I've looked at the 'Tumbler' native client demo, but it's in C++ and seems to be calling a static method for the creation of the object... but how do I create the `PPB_Graphics3D` in C?

The Google doc [here](https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepperc/struct_p_p_b___graphics3_d__1__0) shows it's using an instance of `PPB_Graphics3D` like so:

```
g3d->Create(instance, attribs, &context);
```

But not how to actually create it.

Comment: If you don't want solutions in C++, why did you tag this as C++ then? I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: Because I thought people who know how to use NaCl in C++ might also know the equivalent ways in C pertaining to my topic.

Comment: You can't create C++ objects in C.

Comment: 'PPB_Graphics3D' is part of 'C'... Look at: https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepperc/struct_p_p_b___graphics3_d__1__0

Comment: Ah, I was a mislead -- they're using `::` to denote member fields which happen to be function pointers, not actual methods (which would mean C++).  It's clear once I read a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int32_t PPP_InitializeModule(
    PP_Module module,
    PPB_GetInterface get_browser_interface) {
  PPB_Graphics3D *g3d =
      get_browser_interface(PBB_GRAPHICS_3D_INTERFACE);
}
```

Comment: Cool tnx it worked and that helps me understand how to tackle future issues as well.